# Oracle Indexes and Partitioning

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I'm looking to confirm if you partition the partitioning of Oracle data will also have an affect to reduce the total amount of space used for indexing.

I figured if there are more tablespaces involved, the size of the index data to address that data should be reduced, producing a reduction of the size of the index greater than the reduction on the size of the data.

However, I cannot find anything to verify that.  Right now, I don't have a partitioning license and would like to use that as a minor part of its cost justification (although performance is the biggest one).

Comment: If you are concerned about the disc space for indexes, you may consider Bitmap Indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total size of partioned indexes can be smaller the size of the whole index because the indexes might have less levels in their B-Trees.

If N is the number of rows and p the number of partitions, then the consumed index space can be approximated as:

Unpartitioned: N * [log N]

Partitioned: p * N/p * [log N/p] = N * [log N/p]

[] rounds up to the nearest integer

Answer (score 0):

An index value contains the actual value and the ROWID which is always 10 Bytes.

I don't see any reason why an index on a partitioned table might be smaller than for a normal table - unless you use [Partial Indexes for Partitioned Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-256BA7EE-BF49-42DE-9B38-CD2480A73129.htm#VLDBG14102)